# How to place divs on top of each other aligned horizontal

Tags: html, css, svg

I currently have this;

[image]

But what I want is this;

[image]

How do I css everything, I have tried but I fail to accomplish this. To start with, I need to split my svg in such a way that the top part is behind the login form, and the bottom part in front of the login form. But how to I get to get them over each other in the fist place?

My html;

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="login-page">
            <form action="xxxx" method="post">
                <h1>Wsdfgdfgb</h1>
                <input class="input" type="text" name="_username" placeholder="xxxx"
               value="xxxx" required />
                <input class="input" type="password" name="_password"
               placeholder="xxxx" required />
                <label class="text" for="remember_me">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
            Remember me
                </label>        
                <button>Log In</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="svg-container">
            <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="500px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 1920 960" enable-background="new 0 0 1920 960" xml:space="preserve">
                <g>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#000" d="M64.91,510.275c1.152,15.744,5.364,30.809,10.41,45.648......"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And my CSS;

```
body {
    background: #1AB394; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #1AB394, #008374);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #1AB394, #008374);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #1AB394, #008374);
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #1AB394, #008374);
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}

.login-page {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    width: 360px;
    padding: 8% 0 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.svg-container {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

form h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1a1a1a;
}

form input[type="text"], form input[type="password"] {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    outline: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
}

form input[type="checkbox"] {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    outline: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
}

form .text {
    color: #b3b3b3;
    font-size: 14px;
}

form .err {
    color: #EF3B3A;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

form button {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: 0;
    background: #1AB394;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
    transition: all 0.3 ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form button:hover,form button:active,form button:focus {
    background: #18A689;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let both `.login-page` and `.svg-container` have `position: absolute`, give them both a `z-index`, make the z-index of `.svg-container` higher than the other one and adjust the positions accordingly.

Comment: Is the `z-index` necessary for `.login-page`? It seems switching `.svg-container` to absolute positioning does the trick.

Comment: Having both elements positioned absolute and defining their layer order via z-index is on the safe side, but if that already works, fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a complicated design for it, this is what you could try out, using `float` and centering with `margin`, `width`, and `height`. Then use padding for the north face to keep it at the position you want it at, both the divs.

For example, something simple would be:

```css
#one
    {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 60%%;
    height: 50vw;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20vw 0 0 0;
    }
    
#two
    {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,38,0.6);
    width: 110%;
    height: 10vw;
    margin: auto;
    margin: 10vw 0 0 0;
    padding: 30vw 0 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="one">test
<div id="two">test
</div></div>
```

This is roughly how I would do it. I generally don't overlay things unless it's necessary, I'm better off directly editing both images and overlaying one on the other, and replace it with the edited one.

I'm still learning, there are definitely way better and easier and less confusing ways to do it, but this is my method. I can understand this very easily, so I go with it.

I hope this helps in any way at all.